# 'b' char at first position after split by new line

Tags: python

So i have `string` that i want to split bט `new line`:
This `string` is `process` output:

```
tshark_path=r'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe'
process = Popen([tshark_path, "-D"], stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = process.communicate()
exit_code = process.wait()

lines = [s.strip() for s in output.splitlines()]
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

And each print line always start with `'b'` although this 'b' sign exist only once in my `output` variable (the `process` output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b` means a byte Literal. Please use `decode` to get string.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

tshark_path=r'dir/w'
process = Popen([tshark_path, "-D"], stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = process.communicate()
exit_code = process.wait()

lines = [s.strip() for s in output.splitlines()]
for line in lines:
    print(line.decode('utf-8'))
```